# How can I tell if I am mining

Tags: ethereum

The steps to start mining is confusing.

I created a wallet at

```
https://www.myetherwallet.com/
```

I ran ethminer-cpp and I seem to be doing something

```
  m  18:11:52|ethminer  Got work package: #879ff639
  m  18:11:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:54|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:54|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:55|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:56|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:56|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
  m  18:11:57|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:10
```

I look at my address at

```
https://etherscan.io/
```

but it comes back with

```
Sorry, We are unable to locate the Transaction entry
```

**EDIT 1**

I was imputing the wrong address. I have the correct address now. Instead I am using `nanopool` with `ethminer`. Now I am getting these messages:

```
 ethminer -G --opencl-platform 2 -F http://eth1.nanopool.org:8888/0x...

✘  18:41:19|ethminer  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out

 cl  18:41:21|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
 cl  18:41:24|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
 cl  18:41:27|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
 cl  18:41:30|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.trying in 2... 
JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1... 
  m  18:41:31|ethminer  Waiting for work package...
 cl  18:41:33|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
 cl  18:41:36|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
 cl  18:41:39|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
  ✘  18:41:41|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  18:41:41|ethminer  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out

 cl  18:41:42|cl-0      No work. Pause for 3 s.
```

**EDIT 2**

Feels like I am getting closer because now I am getting different errors. Change to this:

```
ethminer -G --opencl-platform 2 -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=24@0x...
```

Now I get

```
 m  19:09:03|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:01
  ✘  19:09:03|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  19:09:03|ethminer  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32700 : JSON_PARSE_ERROR: The JSON-Object is not JSON-Valid:  Database Error
```

Not sure how to fix this...

**EDIT 3**

By pure luck using `dwarfpool` seems to have gotten all the errors to go away. Still, it must take an awful long time to get `ether`, even tiny amounts?!?

Answer (score 1):

Have you put your own adress as an input on ethminer-cpp?
If yes have you tried to look for your adress' money elsewhere?
(I strongly reccomend to mine with claymore)
The most importand that i forgot to write is that it depends on the pool you are mining to, there is a limit of money you must have mined to be paid.

Comment: Thanks. I am totally new to this. Does claymore support OpenCL? The reason I am using ethminer-cpp is that it supports my Intel GPU through OpenCL.